# Using jQuery to get text content of h4 class="ng-binding" out of Angular scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I would like to get current text content for `<h4 class="ng-binding"></h4>`. Text content is populated dynamically within `angular.js setup` How could I retrieve the text contents using jQuery or JavaScript outside of angular scope / methods.

Comment: Why do you need `jQuery` in `angular` ?

Comment: More of a want then a need.

Comment: `$('h4.ng-binding')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Rayon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377179/using-jquery-to-get-text-content-of-h4-class-ng-binding-out-of-scope#comment60371971_36377179) commented, you just need to use the selector `'h4.ng-binding'`. `h4` is the element and `ng-binding` is the class.

Try:

```
$('h4.ng-binding').text();
```